# Event receiver and handler without SharePoint Server/Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, event-handlers

I need to use some event receiver and handler functionalities into my SharePoint sites, but unfortunately I can't install SP Server or SP Foundation on my computer. I tried to use Visual Studio but this application do not allow create such features without having installed SP Server or Foundation. Is this the only way to get access to event handler and receiver?

If it won't be possible I will just change approach and I will try to create my funcionalities in other way.

Comment: Are you in SharePoint Online? You cannot (should not) create an Event Receiver with SPO.  You have to use SharePoint app development, and create a Remove Event Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option to create Event Receivers in SharePoint Online is to create a Remote Event Receiver. You do not need SharePoint installed to develop this, but you do need a web site to deploy it to. Azure Web Apps work really well for this, but you can use a regular server or another cloud provider if you wish.

Setting up an RER is really simple, but the tooling and documentation are really poor. You do not necessarily need to create an app, but some of the app tooling is pretty helpful.

Because I've written so many Remote Event Receivers, and because the tooling is inadequate, I've released a "Starter Project" on Github that eliminates a lot of the setup. Feel free to use it and provide feedback.

https://github.com/dgusoff/RemoteEventReceiver.Starter